# Deploying Umbraco 8.1.1 to Azure w/SQL Azure DB: Boot Failed

Tags: sql-server, azure, umbraco

I'm trying to develop an Umbraco 8.1.1 site on Azure and am following these steps:

- I create an Azure SQL server database (I don't use any local DB at all).
- I create an empty ASP.NET 4.7 Web App locally and add Umbraco 8.1.1 via NuGet
- I invoke locally and configure my Umbraco application to use the Azure SQL Server DB.  It works without issue.  I can see the database from SQL Server Management Studio no problem.

I then publish the site through Visual Studio 2019 to an Azure Web App, and when I visit it, I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Boot failed: Umbraco cannot run. See Umbraco's log file for more
>   details.
>
> -> Umbraco.Core.Exceptions.BootFailedException: A connection string is configured but Umbraco could not connect to the database.   at
>   Umbraco.Core.RuntimeState.DetermineRuntimeLevel(IUmbracoDatabaseFactory
>   databaseFactory, ILogger logger) in
>   d:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Core\RuntimeState.cs:line 194   at
>   Umbraco.Core.Runtime.CoreRuntime.DetermineRuntimeLevel(IUmbracoDatabaseFactory
>   databaseFactory, IProfilingLogger profilingLogger) in
>   d:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Core\Runtime\CoreRuntime.cs:line 259   at
>   Umbraco.Core.Runtime.CoreRuntime.Boot(IRegister register,
>   DisposableTimer timer) in
>   d:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Core\Runtime\CoreRuntime.cs:line 146

I'm stumped.  How do you configure Umbraco to use an Azure SQL DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you've got the connection string registered in the Web App correctly - I suggest looking at the `Configuration` section for the Web App and setting the configuration string there.  Alternatively, download your web.config file via ftp and compare the connection string in the published version vs. your local version.

You should also check the server or database firewall settings and make sure that Azure services have access:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#connecting-from-azure

Comment: Rob - thanks so much for this answer!  The resolution to my problem was changing the Firewall settings as described in your link, specifically "Allow access to Azure services" setting to "ON".  You've made my day!

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: Mine, it was working very well, all of a sudden this error happened on Azure :(